# Getting session in block- Magento

Tags: magento, session, block

I set a session using `Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setCustomPriceValue($myvalue);` in my frontend phtml file.

To get the value I called `Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getCustomPriceValue();` in one of my block, `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Totals_Shipping`...

But I cant get the value there.

I tried with `Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")` too. But it also fails! :(

Can someone point out why?

Comment: Personally I use `Mage::getSingleton ( 'core/session' )->setJustBought(true)` and `Mage::getSingleton ( 'core/session' )->getJustBought()` it works. Have you any error log ?

Comment: You are doing it right. Just make sure that you have value in the variable $myvalue befor you set or get get it from the session.

Comment: @Renku if I understand correctly u set a variable a in phtml then u are trying to access in Block.
then please make sure ur block instance/method that you are calling must execute after the phtml (where u have set it).

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: @SAM I will check that u said and I am calling session in my frontend `phtml` and calling it in `edit order` page in backend.. Is it cause error? any one know?